# How do I fix the two warnings "warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[256]' [-Wformat]"

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf, c-strings

This is the code ive been trying to fix it for quite a while.. it still refuses to work my friend contacted me to see if i can help her with her code (Below) if someone can tell me whats wrong with it much is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

int main() {
//declarations
double originlat,originlong,deslat,deslong;
double rad1,rad2,rad3,rad4;
char originplace[256], desplace[256];
//input
printf("Enter origin latitude, longitude, and place.\n");
scanf("%lf %lf %[^\n]s",&originlat,&originlong,&originplace);
printf("You entered latitude %0.2lf, longitude %0.2lf, place \"%s\"\n\n", originlat,originlong,originplace);
printf("Enter destination latitude, longitude, and place.\n");
scanf("%lf %lf %[^\n]s",&deslat,&deslong,&desplace);
printf("You entered latitude %0.2lf, longitude %0.2lf, place \"%s\"\n\n",deslat,deslong,desplace);
printf("Origin: %s\n",originplace);
printf("\t%0.2lf degrees is %0.4lf radians (latitude)\n",originlat,rad1);
//process
rad1 = originlat/(180/M_PI);
//output
printf("\t%0.2lf degrees is %0.4lf radians (latitude)\n\n",originlong,rad2);
printf("Destination: %s\n",desplace);
printf("\t%0.2lf degrees is radians (latitude)\n",deslat);
printf("\t%0.2lf degrees is radians (latitude)\n\n",deslong);
printf("The distance from %s to %s is miles.",originplace,desplace);
///:END ToDo

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&desplace` -> `desplace`. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: @Lundin: It is a thinko, not a typo.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Regardless, it is likely not of interest to future readers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil [thinko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60211210/how-do-i-fix-the-two-warnings-warning-format-specifies-type-char-but-the-a/60211374#comment106500503_60211210) 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `&` ampersand operator preceding the arrays of `originplace` and `desplace` passed as last argument to the respective `scanf()` functions, because an array, when used without a specific element index `[i]`, does already decay to a pointer to the first element of the array.

---

Change:

```
scanf("%lf %lf %[^\n]s",&originlat,&originlong,&originplace);
                                               ____________
```

to

```
scanf("%lf %lf %[^\n]",&originlat,&originlong,originplace);
                                              ___________
```

and

```
scanf("%lf %lf %[^\n]s",&deslat,&deslong,&desplace);
                                         _________
```

to

```
scanf("%lf %lf %[^\n]",&deslat,&deslong,desplace);
                                        ________
```

and it should get compiled properly.

I also removed the `s` at `%[^\n]s` because the `%[` format specifier is something quite different than the `%s` format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

For `%[^\n]s`, `scanf` should be passed a pointer to a `char`, that `char` being the first in an array of `char` where the characters that `scanf` reads may be written to. For that conversion, the code has the argument `&originplace`. `originplace` is an array of 256 `char`, so its address, `&originplace`, is a pointer to an array of 256 `char`.

Instead of passing `originplace`, pass the address of its first element, `&originplace[0]`.

As a convenience, you can simply write `originplace`. By the rules of C, this will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. (Whenever an array is used in an expression, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, is the operand of unary `&`, or is a string literal used to initialize an array.)

Also note that `rad1` and `rad2` are printed before they are initialized.

Answer (score 1):

In 0this statement

```
scanf("%lf %lf %[^\n]s",&originlat,&originlong,&originplace);
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

remove the symbol '&'.

Otherwise the expression `&originplace` has the type `char( * )[256]` instead of an expected expression of the type `char *`.

Also in the format

```
"%lf %lf %[^\n]s"
              ^^^
```

remove the last symbol 's'.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `&` (to fix the type),`s` and use a width, check return

```
// scanf("%lf %lf %[^\n]s",&originlat,&originlong,&originplace);
//                 ^    ^                         ^

if (scanf("%lf %lf %255[^\n]", &originlat, &originlong, originplace) != 3) {
  puts("Fail");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays decay as pointers but :

`char array[20];`

`array` - decay to pointer of type `char *`
`&array[0]` - decay to pointer of type `char *`
`&array` - decay to pointer of type `char (*)[20]`

The pointers reference the same place in the memory but have different types.